# laravel : countall tabkle data when get data via paginate funcation

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

i have a Brand table with 50 data in my controller I use this

```
 $brand = Brand::latest()->paginate(5);
 return view('admin.brand.index', compact('brand'));
```

then in my brand view, I use this code for count total

```
<b style="float: right;"> Total Brand: <span class="badge badge-danger">{{count($brand)}}</span></b>
```

but in here count is wrong I expect 50 but its cont as 5 how can I get all count number?

Comment: Did you `dd($brand)` to see what it contains?! That info might already be in there. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The paginate method automatically takes care of setting the proper limit and offset based on the current page being viewed by the user.

So, try `all()` method;

```
$brand = Brand::all();
 return view('admin.brand.index', compact('brand'));
```

And you can use [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) for pagination.

```
<b style="float: right;"> Total Brand: <span class="badge badge-danger">{{count($brand)}}</span></b>
```

> Output will be : 50

Comment: i need pagionation as well

Comment: If it worked, please don't forget to accept the question.